# animate a queue elements in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

So I have a controller like so:

```
var control = angular.module('controllers', []);
control.controller('aboutme', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
      "title": "interests",
      "list": ["cats", "kittens"]
    }, {
      "title": "hobbies",
      "list": ["petting kittens", "playing with kittens", "writing bad stack overflow questions"]
    }]
  }
]);
```

Then within my html, I have the following (using angular-directives addon)

```
<div bs-tabs>
  <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" title="{{ tab.title }}" bs-pane>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in tab.list">{{ i }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will effectively make the tabs and list appear on page. However, what I am trying to do is make each animate *in series one after the other*. Ie, when one finishes animating, animate the next.

How would this be done in angular?

Comment: I think you are using `AngularStrap`.If it's use inject the module `AngularStrap` like `var control = angular.module('controllers', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);`

Comment: yeah. I do that in my app.js section and it seems to work fine, with the way the dependencies work. Eg, `var app = angular.module('app', [..., 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);`. Everything is currently showing up fine, but needs some kick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. Angular disables animation when it is bootstrapping the page.

From Angular Docs:

> ... When an application is bootstrapped Angular will disable animations from running to avoid a frenzy of animations from being triggered as soon as the browser has rendered the screen. For this to work, Angular will wait for two digest cycles until enabling animations. From there on, any animation-triggering layout changes in the application will trigger animations as normal.

So animation will only works for new elements added to your list:

1 - Import angular-animate library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

2 - Enable angular animation module

```
  var control = angular.module('controllers', ['ngAnimate']);
```

3 - Make the transition using css

```
  /*
  Enables the transition
  */
.animation-repeat {
    -webkit-transition:5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:5s linear all;
    -o-transition:5s linear all;
    transition:5s linear all;
}

  /*
  Class added when a new element is added to ng-repeat
  */
 .ng-enter {
   opacity: 0;
 }

/*
  The ng-enter-active and ng-move-active
  are where the transition destination properties
  are set so that the animation knows what to
  animate.
*/
.animation-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.animation-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

But as I said, it will only works for new itens added in ng-repeat. You may use $timeout to delay add the first itens in your page. [Here is the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WD3Q2y8pG3D4ufGbSgeO?p=preview)

Comment: "So animation will only works for new elements added to your list" mmm I'm not sure about this.. with your code that would happen, but I think should be possible

Comment: if you put class="animation-repeat" in the outer ng-repeat it would work for the non-delayed elements

Comment: I mean angular will only add .ng-enter class to objects added dynamically after bootstrapping

Comment: I agree, however those elements would always be added after bootstrapping because belongs to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include 'angular-animate.js' in your html file of your angular project.
2. In your controller file, inject ngAnimate dependency as shown below in the controller code.
3. Lastly, add the following styles to your css file.

```js
//controller code goes here

angular.module('treeApp.controllers', ['ngAnimate']).
    controller('treeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.ideas=[
    {name:"ABC", top:"70% !important", left: "4% !important"},
    {name:"XYZ", top:"68% !important", left: "3% !important"},
    {name:"123", top:"66% !important", left: "2% !important"}];
    });
```

```css
 /*css code goes here*/
 
        .animate-repeat.ng-enter {
        transition: 0.2s linear all;
        opacity:0;
        }
        .animate-repeat.ng-enter-stagger {
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
        transition-duration: 0s;
        }
        .animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
        opacity:1;
        }
```

```html
<!--html code goes here-->

     <div  id="ideadiv" >
        <div class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="idea in ideas">
        <div id="overlay" style='top:{{idea.top}};left:{{idea.left}};'>
        {{idea.name}}
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```